# How to save/restore state of MotionLayout on activity rotation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-motionlayout

Steps to reproduce:
Run an activity with MotionLayout inside it
Transition to a non-initial state
Rotate the device or enable/disable dark mode

Observed: The MotionLayout is in it's initial state
Expected: The MotionLayout is in the state that was shown before the rotation

Should I put the id of the state inside the `savedInstanceState`, and then transition to that state (with 0 duration, so it is instantaneous) inside `onCreate`? This approach I think would work but feels a bit hacky, does anyone know a better solution to this problem?

Here's a recording of the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MotionLayout does not automatically save its state.
The state of the layout can be quite complex.

The most generic way to save the basic stat of a MotionLayout is to save the bundle returned by getTransitionState()
and then call setTransitionState(Bundle b) on restore

Comment: Ok, this works like a charm if the motion layout is inside its end state. But if I setTransitionState when the motion layout is supposed to be in its start state, it auto-transitions to the end state. Do you have any suggestions on how to disable this auto-transition behavior? (in the scene file auto transition is not set)

Comment: Please see this question for further clarification and code/gif: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048418/how-to-restore-transition-state-of-motionlayout-without-auto-playing-the-transit

Answer (score 1):

I know I come a bit late to the party, but this may help someone in the future!

I had a similar problem with the Motion layout and all solutions I found resulted in rendering problems when scrolling my motion layout again, especially for an image that disappears on scroll, so I came up with the following for a **Fragment**

Save the progress of the MotionLayout inside a viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class OverviewViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    ...
     var motionProgress = 0.0f
    ...
}
```

In the fragments onPause save the progress state of the MotionLayout:

```
 override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    viewModel.motionProgress = motionLayout.progress
}
```

And in your onCreateView() method you set the progress to your layout:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
     ...
     motionLayout.post{
        motionLayout.progress = viewModel.motionProgress
    }
    ...
  }
```

For anyone wondering, I have tried saving a local variable in onSaveInstanceState() but I had problems with this method not being called when using NavigationComponents

Hope it helps, Cheers!