# Changing the orientation/ configuration resetting the motion layout to start constraint set

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation, android-motionlayout

I have an activity that supports landscape and portrait orientation. The root layout of the activity is a motion layout. After the motion layout animation, if I change the device orientation, the UI goes back to the start constraint set. How can this be avoided?

Comment: Last time I checked motionlayout doesn't implement any state save/restoration mechanism. You can extend it to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66647252/9241978